# BackboneJS - View class array variables retained after re-instantiation

Tags: backbone.js

I encounter a scenario/bug which I can't explain, as I have a Backbone View class with array variable, but the variable value persist even after I re-instantiate it. The backbone view has following setup:

```
var TestView = Backbone.View.extend({
    a:"",
    b:"",
    items:[],
    initialize:function(){

    },
    add:function(value){
        this.items.push(value);
    }
});
```

Here's how I instantiate the class:

```
this.formView = new TestView();
this.formView.add('halo');
this.formView.a = 'abc';

this.formView = new TestView();
this.formView.add('test');
this.formView.b = 'bcd';

console.log("a - " + this.formView.a);
console.log("b - " + this.formView.b);
console.log("items - ");
console.log(this.formView.items);
​
```

Result:

```
a -  
b - bcd 
items -  ["halo", "test"]
```

Surprisingly, the array variable 'items' persist and it shown both ['halo','test'] together. But not for the normal variables.

Here's the JsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mochatony/2SSVM/8/).

It is solvable by clearing the array at initialize function.

```
    initialize:function(){
      this.items = [];  
    },
```

But I would like to know is this a bug or I misunderstood something.

Comment: I think for some reason formView during re-instantiation is not instantiating after all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the issue is tricky but it has an explanation.

First of all is not good idea to define *instance variables* in a *class context* and this is what you are doing with this:

```
var TestView = Backbone.View.extend({
  a: "",
  b: "",
  items: []
});
```

This is one of the reasons [Model.defaults](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) exists. You rather should to this:

```
var TestView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.a = "";
    this.b = "";
    this.items = [];
  }
});
```

What is happening in your example code is that all the new references of `TestView` will share the same instances of `String` and `Array`. this is because changing the Array in one instance will reflect in the other instance.

The most tricky thing, and you was agile to observe, is that it looks like the sharing behavior is not happening with the Strings but in fact it is happening.

What is happening is that when you do this:

```
this.formView.a = 'abc';
```

You are not *transforming* the String instance but replacing it for a new one so the original String instance remains untouched.

I would like to offer an example of *manipulating* the String in one `TestView` instance and seeing the changes reflect in the other `TestView` instance but I don't found any [JS String method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) that manipulates the String in-place.

Comment: Thanks for the editing @muistooshort... and congrats for the 100k, or should I say thanks for the 100k :)